# How to configure bootloader to boot the new kernel?

Tags: boot, linux-kernel, upgrade, boot-loader, u-boot

I succesfully upgraded linux kernel from 2.6.32.61 to 3.0.7 on BeableBoard-xM, following the steps below:

1. download and untar kernel sources 3.0.7 from kernel.org
2. copy kernel sources on `/usr/src`
3. configure kernel (`make menuconfig`)
4. build kernel (`make`)
5. install kernel (`make install`)

However, after rebooting BB-xM, `uname -r` shows: 2.6.32. It seems to me, that bootloader *(U-Boot)* has to be manually configured in order to boot the new kernel.

```
root@beagleboard:/boot# ls -l
total 14172
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      74 Jun 15  2013 MLO -> MLO-beagleboard-1.5.0+r24+gitr04b1732220078d47c18a84cbafc52e45db71f13d-r24
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   23852 Jun 14  2011 MLO-beagleboard-1.5.0+r24+gitr04b1732220078d47c18a84cbafc52e45db71f13d-r24
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  373953 Jul 26  2011 Module.symvers-2.6.32
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1451022 Jul 26  2011 System.map-2.6.32
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  225447 Feb 13 16:05 System.map-2.6.32.61
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  225447 Feb 13 16:03 System.map-2.6.32.61.old
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  605665 Mar 29  2014 System.map-3.0.7
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   73996 Jul 26  2011 config-2.6.32
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  284788 Apr  1  2011 u-boot-beagleboard-2011.02+r75+gitrc7977858dcf1f656cbe91ea0dc3cb9139c6a8cc8-r75.bin
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Jun 15  2013 u-boot-scripts
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      83 Jun 15  2013 u-boot.bin -> u-boot-beagleboard-2011.02+r75+gitrc7977858dcf1f656cbe91ea0dc3cb9139c6a8cc8-r75.bin
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      13 Jun 15  2013 uImage -> uImage-2.6.32
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3203088 Jul 26  2011 uImage-2.6.32
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1402688 Feb 13 16:05 vmlinux-2.6.32.61
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1402688 Feb 13 16:03 vmlinux-2.6.32.61.old
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5144292 Mar 29  2014 vmlinux-3.0.7
```

Any ideas how can I configure bootloader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make an uImage with your new kernel: `make uimage` and copy it to e.g. `/boot/uImage-3.0.7`. Then you can:

- either make uImage point to it: `cd /boot; ln -sf uImage-3.0.7 uImage`,
- or copy: `cd /boot; cp uImage-3.0.7 uImage`.

Could you post the output of `ls -l /boot`?

Alternatively, you can adjust the U-boot script to load the new uImage-3.0.7. I assume it is under directory `u-boot-scripts`.

Comment: +1 for brief and concise answer. I tried making uImage, but ends up with error as I 'm missing package uboot-mkimage. Command `opkg install uboot-mkimage` refers `Unknown package 'uboot-mkimage'.`.

Comment: Problem solved after running `opkg install uboot-mkimage-dev`. `make uImage` ends up: `Image arch/arm/boot/uImage is ready`. Is `uImage` what I 'll have to copy to `/boot`?

Comment: Yes: `cp arch/arm/boot/uImage /boot/uImage-3.0.7`then `ln -sf uImage-3.0.7 /boot/uImage`

Comment: Unfortnately, during booting procedure, system freezes after `Uncompressing Linux... done, booting the kernel.` What could be wrong? Do I have to edit any of the boot scripts?

Comment: Check bootargs, what was console= setting for 2.6.32 kernel, what should it be for 3.0.7. IIRC it used to be console=ttyS0 then changed to console=ttyAMA0.

Comment: @joe kul I found that on Linux kernel versions 2.6.36 and newer, ttyO2 is using instead of ttyS2. For this reason, I copied a uEnv.txt on the boot partition (`console=ttyO2`) but now boot procedure fails with: `Waiting for root device /dev/mmcblk0p2...`. What I 'm missing?

Comment: Compare the config of the old and the new kernel. Are you missing the needed drivers?

Comment: Kernel 3.0.7 wasn't properly configured.